# Why Independent Variables are not Correlated?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I understand why there are some dependent variables that can be uncorrelated, the random variables $(,)$ that are uniformly distributed on the unit circle in the plane. Obviously they expected area generated by the $(X,Y)$ points around their means will be compensated such that it gets to $0$.

I also understand the meaning of the covariance, such that it is the expected area taking as origin the mean of the variables. Also, I understand the formula of why two random independent variables are uncorrelated, what I don't understand it's the intuition behind that. Could some one enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

Correlation is a gauge of the *linear* relationship between two random variables.

If they are independent then they have *no* relationship, so they certainly cannot have a *linear* relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Note an equivalent definition of independence is that real-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if for all measurable functions $f,g$ with finite expectation, we have

$$E[f(X)g(Y)]=E[f(X)]E[g(Y)].$$

Clearly a special case of this is that $X,Y$ are uncorrelated:

$$E[XY]=E[X]E[Y].$$

Comment: I understand the formula, it's just the intuition. Like why E[XY] and E[X]E[Y] are different for dependent variables? How can I interpret this geometrically.

Comment: @maenju Hm well as you note you can interpret being uncorrelated as saying that the expected signed area of the rectangle with one corner at origin $(E[X],E[Y])$ and opposite corner at $(X,Y)$ is zero. By the same token, independence says the expected signed area of the rectangle with one corner at origin $(E[f(X)],E[g(Y)])$ and opposite corner at $(f(X),g(Y))$ is zero for any transformations $f,g$; it is a *very* strong condition.